# elassandra geopoint mapping fails

Tags: geopoints, elassandra

I cannot map a geopoint with elassandra and the cassandra-express driver.

geopoint UDT:

```
manageESIndex: true,
udts: {
  geopoint: {
    lat: 'double',
    lon: 'double'
  }
}
```

cassandra table elastic mapping:

```
location: {
  type: 'frozen',
  typeDef: '<geopoint>'
}
...
es_index_mapping: {
  discover: '.*',
  properties: {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting elastic mapping is:

```
"location": {
    "type": "nested",
    "cql_collection": "singleton",
    "cql_udt_name": "geopoint",
    "properties": {
        "lat": {
            "type": "double",
            "cql_collection": "singleton"
        },
        "lon": {
            "type": "double",
            "cql_collection": "singleton"
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the mapping does not produce a geo_point, but a lat / lon pair. This does not work when trying to do a distance search. It seems that when using 'discover' the mapping properties are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in a similar problem with a different type/column.

The documentation says that when you use:

```
discover: '.*'
```

It discovers all the columns, but you can *override* with:

```
properties: {
  <column-name>: {
    type: '<specific-type>',
    cql_collection: 'singleton'
  }
}
```

The truth is that the **override** does not actually happen. (Tried with the latest, version 6.2.3.8 of Elassandra.)

I found out that it was much easier to just spell out all the columns and create my mapping that way and never use the `discover: ...` field.

However, I use the `discover: ...` once to get the default mappings and get an idea of what I should use in my own definitions. Often, though, it's somewhat wrong and I need to do small tweaks. Yet, in the end, it worked great for me once I removed the `discover: '.*'` line.

One thing that is very important is the `"cql_collection": "singleton"`. Without it, the default is to create columns as `set<>` or `list<>` instead of plain `int` or `text`, etc. They say in the docs that this is because that's how Elasticsearch expects the data. I would imagine that having `set<>` or `list<>` is going to make things much more complicated and harder to read/write. I guess I'd have to test to see whether it works better or not with a corresponding benchmark test...

Comment: In the discover field, you should set an exclusion pattern of the columns you don't want to map automatically... it's a bad UX and will be improved in a future elassandra release

Comment: @barth, that will be a great improvement! Reading the docs, it did sound like it was already working with that future improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a real example of using `geo_point` data type with `elassandra` from [here](https://medium.com/rahasak/elasticsearch-geo-point-queries-with-scala-d5b9413cbd14)

Comment: This is not a good answer. If that page gets removed, the link will be broken and the answer is definitely worthless. You need to copy the important material on Stackoverflow to make your answer useful.